# Java Card Layouts using Choice

Tags: java, awt

I want to create a program with a GUI where I have a `Choice` with three different options.

I have to realize it with `CardLayout` but my problem is that I don't know how to switch the `CardLayoutPanel` to the one I selected in the `Choice`.

```
Choice ch       = new Choice();
Panel cl        = new Panel(new CardLayout());

Panel one       = new Panel();
Panel two       = new Panel();
Panel three     = new Panel();
```

and in the constructor I have:

```
// CARD LAYOUT PANELS
cl.add(one, "1");
cl.add(two, "2");
cl.add(three, "3");

f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

// CHOICE-OPTIONS
ch.add("one");
ch.add("two");
ch.add("three");
```

How can I add an `ActionListener` to switch between the different `Panel`s using the `Choice` ?

(Please don't comment google it - I already did, otherwise I wouldn't ask)

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using pure AWT components instead of Swing components (`JPanel`, `JComboBox`)?

Comment: Have a look at the [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) Oracle Tutorial. It also contains an example for switching the cards via an `ItemListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (Short Self Contained Correct Example). Notes after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class AwtTest0 extends WindowAdapter implements ItemListener {
    private Frame  frame;
    private Panel  cards;

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
        if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Object obj = event.getItem();
            String name = obj.toString();
            layout.show(cards, name);
        }
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private Panel createCard(String text) {
        Panel card = new Panel();
        Label label = new Label(text);
        card.add(label);
        return card;
    }

    private Panel createCards() {
        cards = new Panel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(createCard("1"), "one");
        cards.add(createCard("2"), "two");
        cards.add(createCard("3"), "three");
        return cards;
    }

    private Panel createChoice() {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        Choice ch = new Choice();
        ch.add("one");
        ch.add("two");
        ch.add("three");
        ch.addItemListener(this);
        panel.add(ch);
        return panel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new Frame();
        frame.addWindowListener(this);
        frame.add(createChoice(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createCards(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AwtTest0 instance = new AwtTest0();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> instance.showGui());
    }
}
```

- In method `main` I call method `invokeLater` which explicitly launches the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (Event Dispatch Thread). The GUI must run on this thread.
- In order to cause the application to terminate when you click the *close window* button (which is usually an `X` in the top corner of the window), you add a [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).
- When you add components to the `Frame`, you are actually adding them to the [content pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) which is a `Panel` that has `BorderLayout` [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).
- `Choice` does not support `ActionListener`, it supports `ItemListener`. Hence the above code implements `ItemListener`.

Comment: At which part of your SSCCE is it possible to add different things like different textfields to each created card?

Comment: @holyshoti see method `createCard`. I just added a `Label`. You can add whatever components you like to each card.